# Amazon Elasticsearch service Kibana's error: "Tenant indices migration failed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I got my `Elasticsearch` service disk storage space totally used, henceforth I had to increase the space, which worked. However, after that `kibana` stopped working with error on kibana URL as `Tenant indices migration failed`.

I've tried multiple links but most of them are pointing towards `opendistro` related settings which I am not able to access in this case as my configuration is over `Amazon Elasticsearch service`. One of the closest issue is [About “Tenant indices migration failed” error in kibana](https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/about-tenant-indices-migration-failed-error-in-kibana/138/33)

Below is the screenshot from my kibana:
[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Seems there's still an open issue about it: https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/security-kibana-plugin/issues/102

Comment: Thanks for the response @Val any possible fix or workaround for now?

Comment: Well, you need to ping the opendistro guys in that thread I guess. Or use a [real stack](https://www.elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service) :-)

Comment: @Val , I also wanted to mention but you gave it a nice name uses a real stack :D

Comment: Yeah, it's more like a joke... but still, I can't help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a workaround for Amazon's `Elasticsearch` which worked for me for the time being, and may help others as well who are facing the same problem with this service in future until fix is finally added to `AWS`, I've added the step below:

> 1. Once you encounter this error, wait for your nodes(data nodes, if dedicated nodes are present) to be active.
> 2. Click on `Edit domain` in Elasticsearch service page on AWS.
> 3. Change **EBS storage size per node** by 1GB (*this will cause migrations to happen again and possibly fix indices migration error*).
> 4. Click `Submit`, and wait for domain to become active, once active try testing kibana url.
> 5. If it does not work try changing **EBS storage size per node** by 1GB again.
> 6. Last resort to be try changing **Instance type** and again after domain is active switch to previous type.

I've got this working solution by trial and error only. I am open for discussion on the same.

Comment: Great, glad to made it work. you can also add these steps on the open github issue

Comment: Certainly, I will add these there as well.

Comment: It didn't work for me. After change EBS storage size again and again the Domain Status is stuck in "Processing" for more than 24 hours. Status in Kibana is: "plugin:opendistro_security@7.1.1 = Tenant indices migration failed". Shards list (/_cat/shards) show two shards for ".opendistro_security" one "STARTED" and one "UNASSIGNED".

Comment: This should only be done once tenant is active after processing. If it is taking more than 24hours, there is something wrong with your domain, tou might need to try connecting with aws support.

Answer (score 1):

I was running Kibana in Docker, so in my case I used this environment variable in my `docker-compose`:

```
environment:
  - OPENDISTRO_SECURITY_MULTITENANCY_ENABLED=false
```

Reference: https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/security-kibana-plugin/issues/102

Comment: Thanks for the solution, yes, this  is one way to make this work, however if multi-tenancy is required as in my case then we can't make it false.